# Is this white root rot on my philodendron?

Tags: pests, fungus, roots

[image]I got this plant from my mother, who had been keeping it in a pot that doesn't seem to drain. I was digging around to see if there was gravel at the bottom or if I'd need to repot, and discovered this mold. Not sure if it's white root rot or something more harmless. I'm relatively new to gardening so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I am not too sure but this could very well be Mycelium. But I am pretty sure the fuzzy cloud is definitely some mold.  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29657/how-can-i-discourage-mycelium-and-other-fungi-growth-in-containers

Comment: Thanks @4-K. I ended up trimming the roots and repotting in new soil+a new pot, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I think you did right. Just make sure you check the roots again after some time to check whether the mood has returned or not. Just be careful with the roots and don't disturb them too much. I think you were supposed to was the roots. But not completely  sure about that.